# SimpleXML parse multiple tags with same name

Tags: php, mysql, xml, parsing, simplexml

please, I need parse XML file with cars information. I done everything in cars, photos, but I need in extra table have id, foreign key to id for cars table, and all car have random of equipment_id.

I need get this into "equipment" table:

```
  <equipment>
  <equipment_id>eq_co_driver_airbag</equipment_id>
  <equipment_id>eq_driver_airbag</equipment_id>
  <equipment_id>eq_abs</equipment_id>
  <equipment_id>eq_aut_aircon</equipment_id>
  <equipment_id>eq_dalk_centr</equipment_id>
  <equipment_id>eq_el_contr_win</equipment_id>
  <equipment_id>eq_el_contr_mirrors</equipment_id>
  <equipment_id>eq_lite_disky</equipment_id>
  <equipment_id>eq_immobilizer</equipment_id>
  <equipment_id>eq_mlhovky</equipment_id>
  <equipment_id>eq_adjustable_drive_wheel</equipment_id>
  <equipment_id>eq_original_autoradio</equipment_id>
  <equipment_id>eq_on_board_comp</equipment_id>
  <equipment_id>eq_steering_booster</equipment_id>
  <equipment_id>eq_leather_trim</equipment_id>
  <equipment_id>eq_ASR</equipment_id>
  <equipment_id>eq_stresni_sibr_el</equipment_id>
  <equipment_id>eq_ton_skla</equipment_id>
  <equipment_id>eq_venkovni_teplomer</equipment_id>
  <equipment_id>eq_adjustable_seat</equipment_id>
  </equipment>
```

I can't create correct import script.

Here is one car from my XML file:
http://pastebin.com/Yyr1GXyb

And here is list of one car via print_r:
http://pastebin.com/csQpQSDs

I tried this:

```
echo "import equipment .. ";
foreach ($xml->cars->car->equipment as $data) {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO equipment (cars_id, equipment_id)
        VALUES
        ($id_car, \"$data->equipment_id\")")
        or die(mysql_error());
    $id_car++;
}
echo "OK\n";
```

and this

```
echo "import equipment .. ";
foreach ($xml->cars->car as $entry) {
    foreach ($entry->equipment as $data) {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO equipment (cars_id, equipment_id)
        VALUES
        ($id_car, \"$data->equipment_id\")")
        or die(mysql_error());
    }
    $id_car++;
}
echo "OK\n";
```

but without success

I can't figure out. Please help me. Thank you very much!

Comment: Use DomDocument instead which makes it more easy

Comment: Is not possible with SimpleXML? Want to use SimpleXML, I thin it's possible. I don't know how use DomDocument for this action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

```
echo "import equipment .. ";
foreach ($xml->cars->car as $entry) {
    foreach ($entry->children()->equipment->equipment_id as $data) {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO equipment (cars_id, equipment_id)
        VALUES
        ($id_car, \"$data\")")
        or die(mysql_error());
    }
    $id_car++;
}
echo "OK\n";
```

Comment: You should collect a bunch of rows to insert, then fire the query. Not for the single row. Better even, use prepared statements to pump data into the db. See [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli).

Comment: Or even better, directly convert the XML via Mysql. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-xml.html